# Solution of the two-body problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, lagrangian-formalism, orbital-motion

I'm self-studying Lagrangian Mechanics using Goldstein's *Classical Mechanics*, supplemented with Lemos's *Analytical Mechanics*, a modern version of the same, and Landau and Lifshitz's *Mechanics*. Currently I'm studying Kepler's two-body problem. I've tried to come up with an approximate solution for the same by considering $M\gg m$. That is, we ignore the movements of the more massive body and consider it fixed at the origin.

The lagrangian for the system will be
$$\mathcal L=\frac12m\dot r^2+\frac12mr^2\dot\phi^2+\frac{GMm}r.$$
$\phi$ is a cyclic coordinate, thus we have
$$mr^2\dot\phi=l=\text{constant.}$$
And using
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial\dot r}=\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial r}$$
we have
$$m\ddot r=mr\dot\phi^2-\frac{GMm}{r^2}.$$
Now I used chain rule
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}=\dot\phi\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\phi}$$
to get
$$\ddot r=-\frac{2l^2}{m^2r^5}\Big(\frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm d\phi}\Big)^2+\frac{l^2}{m^2r^4}\frac{\mathrm d^2r}{\mathrm d\phi^2}.$$
The final DE simplifies a lot with the substitution $r=\dfrac1u$.
$$\frac{\mathrm d^2u}{\mathrm d\phi^2}+u=\frac{GMm^2}{l^2}.$$
Now, I assumed that the mass $m$ starts with $\mathbf r_0=r_0\mathbf i$ and $\mathbf v_0=v_0\mathbf j$. And the angular momentum $l$ is the same everytime, we can write $l=mr_0v_0$, giving us
$$\frac{\mathrm d^2u}{\mathrm d\phi^2}+u=\frac{GM}{r_0^2v_0^2}.$$
This can be trivially solved
$$u(\phi)=\frac1{r(\phi)}=\frac{GM}{r_0^2v_0^2}+A\cos\phi+B\sin\phi.$$
The initial conditions $r(0)=r_0$ and $v(0)=v_0$ give
$$A=\frac1{r_0}-\frac{GM}{r_0^2v_0^2},\quad B=-\frac1{r_0}.$$
where to find $B$, I used the previously mentioned chain rule
$$\frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm d\phi}=\frac{mr^2}l\frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm dt}.$$
This gives us the final trajectory of $m$
$$r(\phi)=\frac{r_0^2v_0^2}{GM+(r_0v_0^2-GM)\cos\phi-r_0v_0^2\sin\phi}.$$
Now, here is the problem I'm facing. I had used the book *Calculus: Early Transcendentals* by Anton, Bivens, Davis for studying calculus as approximately a fresher. I had used the 10th edition, where (don't know about the other editions) the author had provided a derivation for the approximate trajectory I want to achieve (same assumptions as mine), purely using the two vector products and some common vector function theorems he had discussed before.

There, he derived
$$r(\phi)=\frac{r_0^2v_0^2}{GM+(r_0v_0^2-GM)\cos\phi}.$$
So somehow, $B$ has to be zero. But I don't see how that's possible, given the initial conditions.

Kindly help me fix this. Tell me if there are any mistakes in my solution or arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial conditions imply $B=0$. This is so, because by your initial conditions. In polar coordinates
\begin{equation}
\vec{r} = r\vec{e_r}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\dot{\vec{r}} = \dot{r}\vec{e_r} + r\dot{\phi}\vec{e_{\phi}}
\end{equation}
Thus $\vec{r} \cdot \dot{\vec{r}}\; \Big|_{t=0} = 0$ means that since $\vec{e_r} \perp \vec{e_{\phi}}$:
\begin{equation}
0=\frac{d}{dt}r = \frac{d\phi}{dt}\frac{dr}{d\phi} = -\frac{\dot{\phi}}{u^2}\frac{du}{d\phi},
\end{equation}
since $r_0 \neq 0$. Since $\dot{\phi}\neq 0 $, it must follow that $\frac{du}{d\phi}\Big|_{t=0}=0$. Thus $B=0$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was thinking if the manipulation I did is even valid or not. Your method is quite good, formal and correct. Thanks a lot again. :)

Comment: You’re welcome ^^

Comment: Any ideas why my chain rule didn't work?

Comment: Also, doesn't this imply that $v(0)=0$. Why would that be the case as the body has initial speed $v_0$?

Comment: You have to differentiate between the coordinate vector $\vec{r(t)}$ and $r(t)$ as the radial coordinate in polar coordinates. Thus you set erroneously $v_0 =\dot{r}$ instead of $\vec{v_0} = \dot{\vec{r(0)}} = r_0 \dot{\phi} \vec{e_{\phi}} $.

Comment: Now I understand this. Last question: how did you get $\frac d{dt}r=0$?

Comment: Hey, I have devised another way to find $B$, given your corrections. We first have the initial "speed" $v_0=\sqrt{\dot r^2_0+r_0^2\dot\phi^2_0}$. Now we use the initial conditions $\dot\phi=\dfrac{v_0}{r_0}$, along with the formula $\dot r_0=\dot\phi_0\cdot\dfrac{dr}{d\phi}\Big|_{t=0}=\dfrac{v_0}{r_0}k$. This gives $$\frac{v_0^2}{r_0^2}k^2+v_0^2=v_0^2\\k=0$$ See if that's legal.

Comment: Because $\vec{e_r}\cdot \vec{e_{\phi}}=r\dot{r} \vec{e_r}\cdot\vec{e_r}=r\dot{r}=0$ for $t=0$, it must follow $r\dot{r}=0$, and since $r_0\neq0$, $\dot{r} =0$.

Comment: your version also looks fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help.